# Using sed to do an in-place rename in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have a folder on OSX with TV programs downloaded from an online DVR. I want to make a list of the programs and format it to match another list for comparison.

When I run the following command in shell, everything works fine and I get the list I want.

```
ls *.mp4 > loaded_shows.txt
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt
cat loaded_shows.txt
```

When I put the same commands into a bash script, sed gives the following error message for each of the in-place replacement even though the script is in the same directory as the files are.

sed: rename(): No such file or directory

And for completeness, here's the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.mp4 > loaded_shows.txt
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt # replace last _ with space
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt # again replace last _ with space
sed -i$0 's/\(.*\)_/\1\ /' loaded_shows.txt # remove the file extension
cat loaded_shows.txt
```

And sample input filenames:

```
666_Park_Avenue_2014-04-22_23.35.mp4
Americans_2014-04-20_22.45.mp4
Scandal_2014-04-20_21.00.mp4
The_Voice_of_USA_2014-04-22_19.30.mp4
```

How can I get sed to work in the bash script?

Comment: How are you running the Bash script? Does it create loaded_shows.txt still?

Comment: I found the what I did wrong. The problem was with the formatting of the -i parameter. 

I saw the example somewhere without further explanation. I tried several ways of telling sed not make a backup of the file and -i$0 was the only example I found that seemed to work on OSX. After reading a bit more right after posting this question I realized that -i$0 won't work in the script. 

I replaced it with -i '' (a space between) and now the script works and creates loaded_shows.txt. 

Some examples suggested using -i'' (no space between) which doesn't work on OSX.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I suggest `-i .bak` as the argument.  `$0` might work; it is the name of the script, but if it has path information in `$0`, you're hosed.

Comment: I had same issue. I do not need to have backups of files - yes I know what I am doing ;-). The space and two double quote after -i  does the job: _`sed -e 's,2016-11-03.01,2016-11-03.02,g' -i ""  `find src web -type f``_

Answer (score 0):

You've already noted your error with sed's `-i` option.  Well done for finding it.  :)

If the comments in your script are an indication of what you're trying to achieve, I'd actually refactor the script to use sed in a pipe, just once, looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mp4; do
  echo "$f" | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\).mp4$/ \1 \2/'
done > loaded_shows.txt
```

Running sed fewer times is more economical, and opening/closing your text file only once is lots more economical.  Because, you know, a millisecond wasted is a millisecond lost.

I should point out the `for` loop here.  Generally, when you're running through lists of files in a shell script, you want to use `for` rather than parsing the output of `ls`.  [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is a well known gotcha in the world of shell scripting, and it's best not to allow yourself bad habits like that, even in small scripts in controlled environments.

Comment: Can you optimize further: `printf "%s\n" *.mp4 | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\).mp4$/ \1 \2/' > loaded_shows.txt` with one invocation of sed for all file names? It might run into problems if any file name includes a newline; otherwise, it should be good, I think.  Your version runs sed once per filename; the original runs `sed` three times for any number of files (a win for it if there are more than three files; yours wins with less than three files).  My suggested revision runs `sed` once regardless of the number of files.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked like a charm and Jonathans suggestion streamlines the script even more.
I was wondering on how to do the sed replacements more effiently, but couldn't figure it out on myself. I know just enough to replace a single occurance, but replacing three things with one command is way beyond my knowledge.
Could either of you break down the sed so I could learn how sed  actually works in these examples?